# I can't load default_head_blocks.xml and default.xml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I tried to load css file from default_head_blocks.xml but nothing happen, so if you can provide what did I do wrong?Is it wrong in structure files or something else ? Thank you

Note : This theme inheritance from magento/blank and is activated it from dashboard.

File :  default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/mystyle.css" />
</head>
```

Structure file :

[image]

Comment: can u please share your theme.xml file's code?

Answer (score 0):

I have included fontawesome in this way

path: app/design/frontend/vendor/name/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

inside the file default_head_blocks.xml I inserted this code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
        <css src="css/fontawesome/font-awesome.css" media="all"/>
        <css src="css/fontpeicon/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" media="all"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

After I inserted the files in here

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/name/web/css/fontawesome/fontawesome.css
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still not working i think mistake here : /vendor/name/ , i think  my directory name is wrong

Comment: Could you please take screenshots and show your code?